# I would like to place two verible in {{ }}

Tags: angularjs

I have a json file, I would like to place '?' insert the numbers 1 ... 10

```
 {
"Daty": [{
    "Data": "2016-02-13",
    "L1": [],
    "L2": [],
    "L3": [],
    "L4": [],
    "L5": [],
    "L6": [],
    "L7": [],
    "L8": [],
    "L9": [],
    "L10": [],
    "Suma": 0
   }    .........
  }]
  }
```

In html:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in Daty" > <td><B>{{x.Data}}</B></td><td ng-repeat="y in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]">{{x.L??????[0]}}</td><td>{{x.L???????[0]}}</td><td>{{x.L??????[0]}}</td>
```

I would like to place '?' insert the numbers 1 ... 10

Answer (score 2):

You can try to access the field with `[]` notation like this:

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in Daty" > <td><B>{{x.Data}}</B></td><td ng-repeat="y in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]">{{x['L'+y][0]}}</td><td>{{x['L'+y][0]}}</td><td>{{x['L'+y][0]}}</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use below concatenation, which accessing object from array.

```
<tr ng-repeat="x in Daty"> 
    <td><B>{{x.Data}}</B></td>
     <td ng-repeat="y in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]">{{x['L'+ y][0]}}</td>

</tr>
```

Comment: Error: missing name after . operator